# Function of that in this sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

> Now that your baby can roll over independently, dont’t be alarmed if
>   you put her to sleep on her back...

In this sentence is `that` the demonstrative determiner or some kind of pronoun?

Because if it is not the determiner, I would start this sentence `Now, when your baby`...

Comment: **that** can introduce a clause expressing a fact and thus the clause can function nominally. Consider the following sentence where the *that*-clause is subject of the verb **indicates**: "{That your baby can roll over at this age}  indicates normal physical development."  With **now**, as in **now that...**, it can be paraphrased woodenly "Given the current fact that {...} "

Comment: In your example, "that" belongs to the category (part of speech) 'subordinator', and its function is 'marker'. "Now" is one of a number of prepositions that license expandable content clauses -- the kind where "that" can be optionally added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say it's a subordinator (or subordinating conjuction) heading the subordinate clause *that your baby roll... *. It's part of the idiom 'now (that)' (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/now-that).